# how do I disable the blinking "current location" in the MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview

Is there a way to have the MapView not show my current location? I'm not *doing anything, as far as I can tell to provoke this behavior, and yet its displaying this flashing blue dot over my current location.

The app I'm writing doesn't want/need for the user to see their location, and the dot is just distracting, but I'm unable to see how I can turn it off.

Also, the cursor button on the lower right hand side seems to be a permanent feature.

Would love to get some guidance on disabling both of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so... it looks like MyLocationOverlay is the key here. If you never apply it, or call enableMyLocation() on it it won't display your location (I guess that should have been obvious)... Still haven't figured out how to get rid of the button in the lower right.